# How does Spring Boot does determine the EntityManager PersistenceContext?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know how the persistence context of the EntityManager is defined (and shared) in Spring Boot servlet stack.
I thought it was tied to the current thread but I have an application that insert a Filter into the filter chain (see security). This filter loads an User from the database using an autowired EntityManager. The purpose is to use this User later into a  service.

But it seems that that the PersistenceContext used into the Filter is not the same than the one used into the services: If I load the same user(same id) into a service from an autowired EntityManager, the resulting object is not the same that the one loaded into the filter:

```
class MyFilter(val entityManager:EntityManager) : Filter {

  override fun doFilter(request: HttpServletRequest,response: HttpServletResponse,
                        filterChain: FilterChain) {

      SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy().context.authentication = 
        entityManager.load(User::class.java,1)

      filterChain.doFilter(request,response)
  }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig(val entityManager: EntityManager) {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain = http.run {
      addFilterAfter(MyFilter(entityManager),LogoutFilter::class.java)
      build()
    }
}

@Service
class MyService(val entityManager:EntityManager) {

  fun compareUsers() : Boolean {

    val securityUser: User = 
      SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy().context.authentication as User

    // A call to the database is done (should take the user from the cache)
    val loadedUser : User = entityManager.load(User::class.java,1)

    // True: The 2 users represent the same object into database
    assert (securityUser.id==loadedUser.id)

    // Returns always false,
    return securityUser==loadedUser
  }

}
```

I checked and the same thread is used for `MyFilter::doFilter` and `MyService::compareUsers` function calls.
It seems that the persistence context is tied to the request only once the user is authenticated.
How can I do to share the PsrsistenceContext?